# Using CSS Modules with Modernizr (class names)

Tags: html, css, module, modernizr, css-modules

Modernizr adds classes to the document's `<html>` tag, e.g. `<html class="no-touchevents">`.

In my code, I used to write something like this.

```
.style { background: green; }
.no-touchevents .style { background: red; }
```

So the element would be green (OK) if the touch is supported and red (error) if it's not. Now with CSS modules, my `.style` class is defined in a single file and gets transformed into something like this.

```
.xR23A { background: green; }
.hjTT7 .xR23A { background: red; }
```

If I wrap my class in a `:global` clause, it should remain unchanged if I understand it correctly. However, this will apply to every nested class, so I will remain with this.

```
.xR23A { background: green; }
.no-touchevents .style { background: red; }
```

How do I solve this to arrive to the desired solution? This is what I am after.

```
.xR23A { background: green; }
.no-touchevents .xR23A { background: red; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should be able to use the paren version of global to only hoise the modernizr portion.

i.e.

```
.style { background: green; }
:global(.no-touchevents) .style { background: red; }
```